# Animating Blender collada export in three.js

Tags: animation, three.js, blender, skin, collada

http://www.diviniaro.com/WGClient/js/three.js/examples/webgl_loader_collada_Gate.html

After trying several things we're just left at a loss to get the exported animation from blender to load. I have noticed a few differences from the example "monster.dae" file in the collada loader. No matter what we've tried the animation just never seems to start.

Other opinions and a second set of knowledgeable eyes would be appreciated. The animations play fine in blender. There are 31 keyframes. There are also no errors on the console.

EDIT:
I think that this issue pertains to these issues with the three.js collada loader.
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2963

Comment: Try and load your collada file with the webgl_loader_collada_keyframe example.

Comment: It was tried. We've also tried exports from Maya and Max using openCollada.